# A problem about the convergence of a power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $\{a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a real sequence  with  $a_n\ge0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. If $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n<\infty$$

I have to discuss the radius of convergence (in $\mathbb R$)  of the power series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}x^n$$
but I don't know  explicitly the terms of the sequence $\{a_n\}$, so I have difficulties to apply the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem.
Any hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A good example of the over-inflated role of Cauchy-Hadamard theorem in curricula. Reading questions on MSE, one could get the impression that this result is the *definition* of the radius of convergence. Which it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you can say is that the radius of convergence $R$ is at least $1$. Note that the series converges for $x=1$, which settles the "at least" claim. Taking $a_n=1/n^2$ shows that $R$ can be exactly $1$. On the other hand, taking $a_n=1/n!$ shows that $R$ may be infinite. I'll leave it up to you to find examples where $R$ is something in between.

(By the way, the index in the second series should start from $n=1$, unless it's supposed to be a trick question.)

Comment: I have edited the index. Thanks.